# HDMI disconnected

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a DELL Inspiron 14 notebook, Ubuntu 19.04 with an AMD radeon video card. I am trying to make an LG ULtrawide Monitor work with my laptop.

Already tested my laptop in a LG TV, and it works perfectly. Also, the LG monitor works with a PC I have, and a PC from a store where I was to check if it were working fine. I am not understanding why this monitor and my notebook can't work togheter even if they are both functional.

Even with the HDMI cable connected, Display settings and xrandr still reports as disconnected like this.

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

Also, when I force the correct resolution of my monitor ( newmode, addmode, 2560 x 1080_60) with xrand, it starts to work partially, rendering just 1/4 ( not exactly ) of the screen. ( the mouse works in the entire screen )

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1080_60.00"
```

Setting it to scale, the screen is black and only the mouse works on the monitor. If I drag any open window to this monitor it appear delayed and repeated.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 1x1 --right-of eDP-1 --mode "2560x1080_60.00"
```

One strange thing that is happening is that the mouse cursor works in the entire screen, even when the monitor is showing the stuff partially

I am using now ubuntu 19.04, but also tested in 18.04, exact same problem. At this moment I am downloading ubuntu 14.04 to test it with an old version of driver/kernel.

xrand:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  48.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1080_60.00  59.98*
```

lspci -vv

```
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon R7 M260/M265
    Physical Slot: 4
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 54
    Region 0: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 5: Memory at c2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at c2040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x4 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00418  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [270 v1] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Capabilities: [2b0 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [2c0 v1] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        PRICtl: Enable- Reset-
        PRISta: RF- UPRGI- Stopped+
        Page Request Capacity: 00000020, Page Request Allocation: 00000000
    Capabilities: [2d0 v1] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        PASIDCap: Exec+ Priv+, Max PASID Width: 10
        PASIDCtl: Enable- Exec- Priv-
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

xrandr --listproviders

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x64 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:AMD Radeon R7 M260 @ pci:0000:04:00.0
```

dmesg shows strange stuff also:

```
[   33.384861] amdgpu: [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
[   33.417539] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: GPU pci config reset
[   35.086922] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
[   35.093000] amdgpu: [powerplay] can't get the mac of 5
[   35.094140] amdgpu: [powerplay] VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value in dependency table. Using Memory DPM level 0!
[   39.516060] i915 0000:00:02.0: HDMI-A-1: EDID is invalid:
[   39.516065]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516066]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516068]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516069]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516070]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516072]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516073]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   39.516074]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   41.291476] amdgpu: [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
[   41.330509] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: GPU pci config reset
```

Comment: In my case it was broken HDMI cable. It works with TV, but didn't work with display. Changing cable helped.